# StringBuilder.Append with float

Tags: c#, asp.net

`StringBuilder.Append` using `float` is truncating the value.  What is it converting to and how can I stop it from truncating?

`AttributeOrder` is type `float` and I am losing precision when building the string.

```
if ( AttributeOrder != 0 ) 
{ 
    if ( Result.Length > 0 ) 
    { 
        Result.Append( " AND " ); 
    } 
    Result.Append( COLUMN_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER ); 
    Result.Append( "=" ); 
    Result.Append( AttributeOrder ); 
}
```

EDIT: This is legacy code, I cannot change the underlying datatypes. The column in SQL Server is a real and the datatype is `float`.  I need to present the `float` as it is filled, as a string for other purposes and not loose precision as is.

Comment: If you can't change the datatype, you can't solve the problem.

Comment: I can't take a float .NET datatype and represent it as a string?

Comment: You can't take a `float` and convert it to a _24-digit_ string.  If you're willing to settle for 9 digits, you can; see the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the `float` to a string using a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString), like this:

```
Result.Append(AttributeOrder.ToString("G9"))
```

Or, alternatively,

```
Result.AppendFormat("{0}={1:G9}", COLUMN_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER, AttributeOrder)
```

However, you will not be able to get more than 9 digits of precision from a `float`, and digits 8 and 9 will be inaccurate.

---

The [`float` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) can only hold seven digits of precision.  As soon as you put the value into a `float` variable, you've irrecoverably lost the precision.  In order to store all 24 digits of precision from SQL Server, you need to use the [`decimal` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx).

Once you change the variable to a `decimal`, `Append` will give you as many digits as you put in.

Comment: Even if you specify the format like this your solution will fall prey to `float's` inability to represent floating point numbers at high precision.

Comment: Yes.  For some reason, I'm assuming that he's aware of that

Comment: The real data type is the same as float(24) — a floating data type with 24 digits to the right of the decimal point.  So, could I safely use "G24" as my format and never loose precision?

Comment: No.  You're losing the precision as soon as youput the value into a `float`.  You need to put the data in a `Decimal`, not a `float`.

Comment: Understand, not my issue, just need to show the float as is, however it got there as a string and not loose anymore precision.

Comment: You can't.  The `float` doesn't _have_ those extra digits, and there is no way to get them back.  You **need** to use a `decimal` instead; it is not possible to do this without storing the number in a `decimal`.  (Or a string)

Comment: Can you discuss garbage collection (creation) in your answer? I'd like a solution that generates no garbage.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette: Calling `AppendFormat()` won't allocate directly.  It looks like the implementation does; see the [source](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs#ad46fb2c09cab59a)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to provide a *representation* of a floating-point number then you should use `System.Decimal` - `System.Single` cannot accurately represent the precision you are looking to display.

This simple example shows the difference:

```
using System;   

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Single s = 1.23456789f;
        Decimal d = 1.23456789m;

        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is legacy code with underlying datatype of SQL Server real.  Is there a max precision I could count on for the formatter?

Comment: If you use the `Decimal` type you don't need to worry about specifying the precision - the representational precision (i.e. the display of the number as a string) will be *exactly* what you set it to.

Comment: @Andrew Hare - A Decimal will display exactly what the stored value is, but this is not necessarily exactly what you set it to!

Comment: @rick schott - I think the precision of the formatter isn't the thing to be concerned about, it's the precision of the variable. If you want more precision, then you should switch to `double`.

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge My issue isn't with the variable, its when it needs to be represented as a string.

Comment: @Andrew, Jeffrey: `decimal` only holds  ~28 significant digits.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Comment: @rick: It's too late.  Once you put the value into a `float`, it is completely impossible to recover the precision.

Comment: Not trying to recover precision from db to float variable, not the question asked.

Comment: @rick - It's not a matter of recovery, it's a matter of choosing the right type to hold your data.  The fact remains that if you wish to represent a floating-point number as a string without any rounding errors then you *must* use a `Decimal`.  A `Single` or a `Double` *cannot* do this because of the particular way in which they have been implemented (for more information on this topic please see http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 2):

Let's have some fun with floats, and see why this isn't working.

Say the 24-digit number 1.23456789012345678901234 is read from a SQL `real` into a .Net `float`.

The float value looks like this in binary: `0 01111111 00111100000011001010010`

The first `0` is the sign bit, indicating the number is positive.
`01111111` is the biased exponent, indicating that the significand is multiplied by 2^0 (or 1).
`00111100000011001010010` is the digits of the number, minus the first bit.

So the float variable now encodes the number 1.00111100000011001010010 in binary.

Let's see what happens when we convert that float into decimal.

```
1 * 1 =                         1
.
0 * 0.5 =                       0
0 * 0.25 =                      0
1 * 0.125 =                     0.125
1 * 0.0625 =                    0.0625
1 * 0.03125 =                   0.03125
1 * 0.015625 =                  0.015625
0 * 0.0078125 =                 0
0 * 0.00390625 =                0
0 * 0.001953125 =               0
0 * 0.0009765625 =              0
0 * 0.00048828125 =             0
0 * 0.000244140625 =            0
1 * 0.0001220703125 =           0.0001220703125
1 * 0.00006103515625 =          0.00006103515625
0 * 0.000030517578125 =         0
0 * 0.0000152587890625 =        0
1 * 0.00000762939453125 =       0.00000762939453125
0 * 0.000003814697265625 =      0
1 * 0.0000019073486328125 =     0.0000019073486328125
0 * 0.00000095367431640625 =    0
0 * 0.000000476837158203125 =   0
1 * 0.0000002384185791015625 =  0.0000002384185791015625
0 * 0.00000011920928955078125 = 0
                                ------------------------
                                1.2345678806304931640625
```

So if we display *all* of the digits of the floating point number we get 1.2345678806304931640625.
So isn't this the number that we want to display? Why is it rounding this number? And why is this value different from the number we started with?

To see why, let's step through a few adjacent floating point values:

```
binary floating point representation   decimal representation
------------------------------------   ----------------------
0 01111111 00111100000011001010000   = 1.2345676422119140625
0 01111111 00111100000011001010001   = 1.23456776142120361328125
0 01111111 00111100000011001010010   = 1.2345678806304931640625
0 01111111 00111100000011001010011   = 1.23456799983978271484375
0 01111111 00111100000011001010100   = 1.234568119049072265625
```

As you can see, the exact same floating point number is used to represent all values in this range: [ 1.234567821025848388671875 , 1.234567940235137939453125 )

Therefore, any decimal digits after the eighth are lost during the conversion to a float, and any that might be displayed are completely meaningless, and are unrelated to the actual value that is being represented.

All decimal digits beyond the eighth are an artifact of rounding to 24-bit binary and converting to decimal, and they carry no actual meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `ToString()` method on your float, like this:

```
if ( AttributeOrder != 0 ) 
{ 
    if ( Result.Length > 0 ) 
    { 
        Result.Append( " AND " ); 
    } 
    Result.Append( COLUMN_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER ); 
    Result.Append( "=" ); 
    Result.Append( AttributeOrder.ToString("0.000000") ); 
}
```

For example, the format specifier above shows 6 decimal places. Replace the `0` with `#` if you don't want to show trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can kill multiple birds with `string.Format()`.  Reduce the lines of code, and display the number to an arbitrary precision.

```
Result.Append(string.Format("{0}={1:0.000000}", COLUMN_ATTRIBUTE_ORDER, AttributeOrder));
```

Comment: You should call `AppendFormat`.  Calling `Append(String.Format(...))` defeats the purpose of the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: You still won't be able to display more precision than the `float` can contain.